# Sending mail of the html report from testcafe, how to achieve this?

Tags: node.js, testing, report, nodemailer, testcafe

Hello I am using the open source testcafe( not the studio) for my project and once my testcafe tests runs it creates a testrail-html report. Now I want to send the report that I got via email. How do I do that. I have used nodemailer and achieved this to an extent, the mail is getting sent with the report attached however the html report that is getting attached to the mail is showing blank, can you help please.

```
var mailer = require("nodemailer");
var smtpTransport = require('nodemailer-smtp-transport');

var transporter = mailer.createTransport(smtpTransport({
    host: 'mailo2.abc.com',
  }));

 // send mail with defined transport object
 var mail = {
    from: '<john.doe@abc.com>', // sender address
    to: "<john.doe@abc.com>'// list of receivers
    subject: "Report for ABC Vital Business Function", // Subject line
    html: "<b> ABC Vital Business Function Report Attached</b>", // html body

    attachments: [{
        filename: 'Report.html,
        filepath:'.. /test-reports',
    }]
}

  transporter.sendMail(mail, function(error, response){
    if(error){
        console.log(error);
    }else{
        console.log("Message sent: " + response.message);
    }

    transporter.close();
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Your `attachments` object looks incorrect. Use the `path` property instead of the `filepath`:

```
attachments: [{
    filename: 'Report.html',
    path: '../test-reports/Report.html',
}]
```